# JS generated page doesn't fully render into html when scraping

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I can't seem to get my python web scraper to work with JS rendered websites that make calls to a server to fill the webpage. Take this website (https://playon.co/#/en/games-lobby) for example, if I use this script:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from lxml import html


class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

url = 'https://playon.co/#/en/games-lobby'
r = Render(url)
result = r.frame.toHtml()
print(result)
```

It works fine for most JS rendered website, just like any other approach, like Selenium, BeatifulSoup, etc., but all of them fail to properly render html when websites make calls to a server to populate the content of the page.

I have found [one similar question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/35050746/) on stackoverflow that seemed to tackle the same problem, but as hard as I tried I just couldn't understand the solution and adopt it in my code. It seems like a tailored solution to that specific question and I can't figure out how exactly it applies to my problem even though it seems similar.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try using dryscrape it claim to scrape any JS site.

Comment: @RajanChauhan Haven't tried that one, I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution you linked to assumes that there is a version of the URL you wish to scrape that provides the data in JSON format.  If you don't have a similar version of the URL you want to scrape, that approach won't be of any use to you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that. Any idea what makes this version of the URL non responsive to standard js scraping?